# Will a Dell/HP/Acer Install disk work on a Packard Bell Laptop

Tags: windows-vista, installation, 64-bit

I would like to get Windows Vista Cheap, I found a site online saying it might be a Dell disk or Acer or HP, I want to know, will this work on my 64 bit laptop ,that is made by Packard Bell, will work for this disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most such disks are used to do a full system restore.  Some will check for hardware IDs to assure it is restoring to the correct hardware and if not, the install will no proceed.

Such disks will also try to load for specific hardware which may or may not exist. The install may fail due to incompatabilities.

The Windows Vista Key(COA) on your laptop also may fail to work.

Comment: By Key do you mean the Key as in Windows key or O

Comment: COA is certificate of authority. (aka the 'windows key). It is the sequence of five numbers, something like this 12345-67890-abcde-12345-54321.

Comment: Thanks my laptop came pre-installed with win-7 that got the dreaded blue screen of death so I never got to install it didn't come with CD :(